# JavaFx : get the last focused table

Tags: java, javafx, focus, tableview, javafx-8

I have a view with two `TableView`s, and I want to get the last selected table, so which table's row was selected last time. I tried:

- `table.isFocused()` but it returns false for both tables, I guess because I have selected a row not the table itself.
- `table.getFocusModel().getFocusedItem() != null`, but it returns true for both tables if I select a row in both table.

So how can I get the last selected table's row, I have a dirty solution, to define an enum and add a listener to the `tableView`'s selection model, but I think there is a simpler way, so do you have any idea? For me the best would be a method that returns true for one tableview and false for the other, of course true for the last selected.

Answer (score 0):

I see the next solution: you have a temporary variable which will point to the last selected node and you listen to 2 table views for focused property:

```
Node lastSelectedTable = null;

tableView1.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue) {
        lastSelectedTable = tableView1;
    }
});

tableView2.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue) {
        lastSelectedTable = tableView2;
    }
});
```

At any time under 'lastSelectedTable' you have a reference to really latest focused table.